# How to implement regularization / weight decay in R

Tags: r, neural-network, regularized

I'm surprised at the number of R neural network packages that don't appear to have a parameter for regularization/lambda/weight decay. I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious. When I use a package like MLR and look at the [integrated learners](http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/integrated_learners/index.html), I don't see parameters for regularization.

For example: nnTrain from the deepnet package:
[list of params](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deepnet/versions/0.2/topics/nn.train)

I see parameters for just about everything - even drop out - but not lambda or anything else that looks like regularization.

My understanding of both `caret` and `mlr` is that they basically organize other ML packages and try to provide a consistent way to interact with them. I'm not finding L1/L2 regularization in any of them.

I've also done 20 google searches looking for R packages with regularization but found nothing. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through more of the models within `mlr`, (a daunting task), and eventually found the `h2o` package learners. In `mlr`, the `classif.h2o.deeplearning` model has every parameter I could think of, including L1 and L2.

Installing `h2o` is as simple as:
`install.packages('h2o')`